# Matlab Deep Learning training progress window won't close

Tags: matlab

I am trying to train a simple image classifier in Matlab 2020b (MNIST dataset), basically following examples in the Matlab documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html).

My problem is that when the training finishes (whether stopped manually or run to completion), it gets stuck on the last iteration. It does not make it to the 'Reached final iteration' message, and I can not close the GUI. This seems to happen about 80% of the time. Sometimes I get lucky and it will finish. I can't find any description of a similar problem anywhere.

Edit: When I came back this morning the training progress GUI had finally updated, and the command window had this message:

Warning: Graphics timeout occurred. To share details of this issue with MathWorks technical support, please include that this is
an unresponsive graphics client with your service request.

```
> In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/TrainingPlotPresenterWithDialog/updatePlotForLastIteration (line 128)
In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/CLITrainingPlotter/updatePlotForLastIteration (line 62)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/TrainingPlotReporter/finish (line 79)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/computeAndReport (line 64)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/finish (line 32)
In nnet.internal.cnn/Trainer/train (line 155)
In nnet.internal.cnn.trainNetwork.doTrainNetwork (line 91)
In trainNetwork (line 181) 
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
Warning: Graphics timeout occurred. To share details of this issue with MathWorks technical support, please include that this is
an unresponsive graphics client with your service request. 
> In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/TrainingPlotPresenterWithDialog/showPostTrainingStage (line 140)
In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/CLITrainingPlotter/showPostTrainingStage (line 66)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/TrainingPlotReporter/reportFinalIteration (line 93)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/computeAndReport (line 64)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/reportFinalIteration (line 57)
In nnet.internal.cnn/Trainer/doFinalize (line 275)
In nnet.internal.cnn/Trainer/finalizeNetwork (line 166)
In nnet.internal.cnn.trainNetwork.doTrainNetwork (line 94)
In trainNetwork (line 181) 
Warning: Graphics timeout occurred. To share details of this issue with MathWorks technical support, please include that this is
an unresponsive graphics client with your service request. 
> In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/TrainingPlotPresenterWithDialog/showPostTrainingStage (line 140)
In nnet.internal.cnn.ui/CLITrainingPlotter/showPostTrainingStage (line 66)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/TrainingPlotReporter/reportFinalIteration (line 93)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/computeAndReport (line 64)
In nnet.internal.cnn.util/VectorReporter/reportFinalIteration (line 57)
In nnet.internal.cnn/Trainer/doFinalize (line 275)
In nnet.internal.cnn/Trainer/finalizeNetwork (line 166)
In nnet.internal.cnn.trainNetwork.doTrainNetwork (line 94)
In trainNetwork (line 181)
```

Comment: There's not enough about the specifics of your approach for anyone to be able to  help you.

Comment: @Curt Please let me know what specific specifics are needed and I can provide them.

Comment: As suggested in the warning, it may be better to contact the MathWorks technical support.

Comment: @m7913d Thanks, I did as you suggested and seem to have a tenable fix which is to launch matlab from command prompt with the option "-softwareopenglmesa"

Comment: @mtrsteve, Thanks for sharing your solution. I voted to reopen your question. Once it is reopened you may consider creating an answer yourself (and mark it as accepted afterwards). Hopefully, others with the same question will find your answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

As per MATLAB support staff, this is a known issue that is being worked on. The workaround is to launch matlab from command prompt with the option "-softwareopenglmesa". This fixed my issue, and makes the deep learning progress monitor usable.